# Memory Leak when using for(object in array) with iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone, memory-leaks, for-loop, instruments

I am running into some serious memory leaks in one of my applications I am building. I have a UINavigatonController that is inside a UITabBarview. Inside the NavView is a MKMap view. When you click an accessory button on a callout a detail view is loaded. In that detail view I am trying to populate a table from a plist using a for(object in array) loop. The plist is an array of dictionaries. I am running though the dictionaries to find one with a key that is the title of the callout and then get an array from inside that dictionary. It all works fine in the simulaor but I am getting massive memory leaks doing it the way I am. Any Idea whats going on?

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad {
        self.title = @"Route Details";
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stopLocation" ofType:@"plist"];
        holderArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [self getRouteArray];
        routeDetails.delegate = self;
        routeDetails.dataSource = self;

    }
    -(void)getRouteArray{

        for (NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in holderArray) {
            //NSString *stopName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"StopName"];
            //NSString *stopName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[dictionary objectForKey:@"StopName"]];

            BOOL testString = [currentRoute isEqualToString:[dictionary objectForKey:@"StopName"]];

            if (testString) {
                routeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dictionary objectForKey:@"RouteService"]];
            }
        }
    }
- (void)dealloc {

    [routeArray release];
    [routeDetails release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

holderArray is an ivar and so is route array. As you can see I have tried a few ways of allocating the nstrings and arrays but all seem to yield the same leaks. According to the performance tool I am leaking from NSCFString, NSCFDictionary, and the NSCFArry. I released the routeArray in the dealloc and it works fine, but if I release holderArray it crashes whenever I go back to my map from the detail view. I guess I am just really unsure as to how to deal with the strings and dictionary used in the for loop.

Just to add the detail view is being created like so:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{


    NSString *selectedRouteName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",view.annotation.title];

    RouteDetailView *rdc = [[RouteDetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"RouteDetailView" bundle:nil];
    [rdc setCurrentRoute:selectedRouteName];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rdc animated:YES];
    [rdc release];


}
```

Sorry if any of the above is unclear. Let me know and I can try to rephrase it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will `testString` be true for at most one key in `holderArray`? If so, you should probably break out of the loop after setting `routeArray`. If not, then you may be setting `routeArray` multiple times, and all but the last array you assigned to it would be leaked.

Also, I don't see you releasing `holderArray`.

Comment: Yes testString will be true at most one time. The reason I did not release holderArray originally was because when I would the app would crash when you go back on the navController. I added the break and replaced the release for holderArray and it seems to be working. Thanks for your help. My mind went to mush after fixing other problems till 4 am that this one drove me nuts, and yet the answer was so simple.